# How to add snippet in slack?

Tags: slack, vscode-snippets

I know what you think, you will probably give me this [slack snippet documentation](https://slack.com/help/articles/204145658-Create-or-paste-code-snippets-in-Slack#:%7E:text=From%20your%20desktop%2C%20click%20the,snippet%20in%20the%20Content%20field.), but sadly I've been here and it's not the one I'm talking about.

I'm talking about snippet like in vscode, in which we can save large amount of prepared text. And will display it just one click or a tab.

Does slack have this kind of feature? I've been searching for awhile but unsuccessful.